# WPF with Linq to SQL, Procedure with timeout

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a WPF application with a Linq to SQL model. In the .dbml file, I have a stored procedure that returns the coordinates of an address. The procedure use the active internet conection to call a google maps "service" and get the coordinates.

The problem is, when the internet conection is slow, or is busy, the procedure takes long time to return the coordinates and I get a TimeOut exception in C#.

I was wondering if is there a way to control If the procedure takes more than x seconds to return, then skip it and continues with the process because the coordinates is not a mandatory information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could do this is to run the SP asynchronously and with a timer, cancel the async process when X seconds have passed.

To accomplish this you could take the easy way and use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

Next, you can create a `CancellationToken` and pass it to the task's start method. When the timer times out (your timer, not the SP), just cancel the task. For a quick way on how to do this I'm going to ask you to read the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036198/does-task-waitint-stop-the-task-if-the-timeout-elapses-without-the-task-finish).

Comment: Thanks the coon, I'll try this approach.