# can calling thread.abort() on a hung thread hang the main thread?

Tags: c#

I have an external library that my code calls that sometimes hangs forever (but only on production!).  I put the part that hangs into a seperate thread so I could just kill it and try again if it times out using the following, but it appears to hang when calling abort:

```
var triesLeft = 5;
while (triesLeft > 0) 
{
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    var t = new Thread(_ => {
                           MethodThatHangsForever10PercentOfTheTime();
                           mre.Set();
                     });
    t.start();

    if (mre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)))
    {
          break; // Success!
    }
    triesLeft--;

    log("this prints once");
    t.abort();
    log("this never prints");
  }
}
```

Is it possible that the spawned thread causes the main thread to hang when calling abort on it?

Comment: Just don't use `Abort`.  It's virtually always the wrong solution to any given problem.

Comment: @Servy - So, what is the recommended solution?

Comment: Well, the ideal solution would be to use code that doesn't break itself 10% of the time.  That's a pretty horrible position to put yourself in.  Either pressure the library to fix its code, contact their support to see if you're simply using it improperly, or find a way to avoid using a broken library method that misbehaves like this.

Comment: Could you move your code into an IIS-hosted wcf-service? You could then get automatic recycling and every other failsafe solution IIS provides.

Comment: Working with buggy third party library, it is sometimes a good idea to move it to another process, and talk with it using some interprocess communication way, like WCF. When library function hangs, just kill and restart the process.

Comment: You mean a process could restart another process?  Wouldn't my process need the ability to start and stop services then?

Comment: You might have luck using Tasks, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036198/does-task-waitint-stop-the-task-if-the-timeout-elapses-without-the-task-finish

Comment: @JohnGibb And how do you plan to stop the `Task` that you've started if the code it is running starts to hang?

Answer (score 1):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is no way to guarantee a thread will end if you call abort. I'm also semi-positive Abort() will block until the exception actually is raised. However, I could be mistaken.

I suggest you take a look at the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyayh29d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There might be something you can glean from this on handling threads.

However, as Servy said, you're probably better off not using Abort. I'm of the same opinion.

Comment: I'm of the same opinion too. +1.