# How to repeat a function call until timeout is undercut in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to repeat a function until the function has no timeout. The function should return something but if it takes too long the function call should be repeated. This is what I have:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => main.getPlaces(field));

while (true)
    {
        if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
        {
            field = task.Result;
            break;
        } else
        {
            task = Task.Run(() => main.getPlaces(field));
            continue;
        }
    }
```

It seems like the function isn't recalled with this setup. The console output just gets slower and slower.

Comment: *"This is what I have"* - okay, and what's the problem? Does it give errors? Not compile? Not do what you wanted?

Comment: I added a little explanation.

Comment: Of what? It's your code.

Comment: My current scenario.

Comment: *"The execution just gets slower and slower."* - depending on what it's doing, unless `getPlaces` is actually being cancelled, it may still be running. Just because you've stopped waiting for it, doesn't automatically mean the task has stopped running. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036260/1250301) for example.

Comment: I never said it stop running. The output just slows down and I can't interpret the result furthermore because my C# knowledge is very limited.

Comment: You start `getPlaces`, you wait 1 second and then start it again. Then you wait 1 more second and start it again...and so on. Depending on how long `getPlaces` actually takes, you could have dozens of instances of the task running *at the same time*. No wonder it's getting slow.

Comment: I assume you are not cancelling the old task upon calling the new task.
It might be creating multiple tasks. 

Warning: Haven't tested by executing.

I would try this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/4036260/4052549

Comment: He's calling the function from within itself, and for no apparent reason.  Julian, what exactly are you trying to do with this code?  a simple while loop would do what you actually described.

Comment: @Trey, `getPlaces` could be endless. That's why I would like to catch this case and restart it until it has an end. This approach is horrible, I know, but it would be enough for my purposes.

Comment: Then you need to STOP `getPlaces` - which would require you to start the task with a cancellation source. Cancel the task after the wait expires without getting a result. And then in your `getPlaces` function actually respond to the cancellation and stop doing whatever it's doing.

Comment: can you please tell me what function the while(true) is in?

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args)` in class `Program`. Complete code: https://pastebin.com/g2snC1bh

Comment: Thanks.  SO walk me through what you want, and I'll get you there?

Comment: I would like to restart the method until the method has no timeout because it's internal calculation would be endless.

Comment: Ok thanks @Julian, if you put break points in, what is not working?  Your code/idea sounds solid(not an approach I have ever used...)  But without debugging on my end I need more information about what is failing.